# How to create Makefile to compile a single arbitrary filename in C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I'm very new to C programming and I want to know what to write in a Makefile to compile a single .c file.

Say I have a multiple `.c` files in one folder )namely `sample1.c`, `sample2.c`, `sample3.c`, etc) and I only want to compile a specific filename. 
I want to only type "`make sample2`" which will compile and have an output called `sample2` (pretty much the `.c` name will be maintained).

I've read several solutions and someone might have suggested this but didn't work.

```
SRC =  $(shell find . -type f -name \*.c)

executable: $(SRC:.c=.o)
    gcc -std=gnu99  $@ $^
```

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: that `find` command is saying to start at the root node of all the hard disks on the computer.   This is because it is using a 'non-relative' path I.E. `\*.c` which will find each and every *.c file in the root directory.  Suggest changing the line to: `SRC =  $(shell find . -type f -name .\*.c)`   However, the `make` utility (for gnu) has this command: `SRC := $(wildcard *.c)` which will find all the 'c' files in the current directory.

Comment: If it were me, I would be enabling the warning when compiling.  I.E. at a minimum use: `<tab>gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion  $@ $^ -I.` ... then any library paths, followed by any libraries needed by the code.

Comment: You don't need a `makefile` for that: `make sample2` will compile `sample2.c` to create the program `sample2`.  You could use `/dev/null` as the name if you want: `make -f /dev/null sample2`.  Etc.  That compiles with the default options, of course.  If you want to use more stringent flags, then you might do `echo 'CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11 -O3 -g' > makefile` and then `make sample2`.

Comment: @user3629249 Re "every file in root dir": I would not think that "\*.c" will arrive at the find command as-is; ia POSIX shell will probably remove the backslash in the argument and preserve the literal "\*". The details depend on the environment: In a POSIX system the FS root is a forward slash anyway, so even if the baskslash is passed to `find` it will not match anything. With MS Windows it's more involved: Cygwin will not translate Windows paths to POSIX paths in arguments to POSIX programs like `find`, but MSYS(2) might. Finally, the `-name` argument does *not* tell find where to search.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider,  Your right, I'm wrong.  What was I thinking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>*Converting a comment into an answer.*</sup>

You don't need a `makefile` for that: `make sample2` will compile `sample2.c` to create the program `sample2`.

You could use `/dev/null` as the name of the `makefile` if you want (or if you need to ignore an existing `makefile`):

```
make -f /dev/null sample2
```

That compiles with the default options, of course. If you want to use more stringent flags, then you might do this (assuming that the existing `makefile` is expendable):

```
echo 'CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11 -O3 -g' > makefile
make sample2
```

or some variant on that theme, such as:

```
make -f /dev/null CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11 -O3 -g" sample2
```

In short, `make` knows how to compile single C files into the executable of the corresponding name (minus the `.c` suffix) without needing any explicit `makefile`.  You can tweak how it compiles that file if need be.